# source repository does not work to publish messages on pub/sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-source-repositories

I've followed below link in order to integrate my repository to pubsub.
https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-adding-pubsub-notifications#before-you-begin

However, my repository does not work to publish pubsub messages.
This is the description of my repository:

```
$ gcloud beta source repos describe test
name: projects/[my-project-id]/repos/test
pubsubConfigs:
  projects/[my-project-id]/topics/test:
    messageFormat: JSON
    serviceAccountEmail: xxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
    topic: projects/[my-project-id]/topics/test
size: '2425'
url: https://source.developers.google.com/p/[my-project-id]/r/test
```

The topic 'test' has a subscription named 'test-subscription'.

```
$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions describe test-subscription
ackDeadlineSeconds: 10
expirationPolicy:
  ttl: 2678400s
messageRetentionDuration: 604800s
name: projects/[my-project-id]/subscriptions/test-subscription
pushConfig: {}
topic: projects/[my-project-id]/topics/test
```

So I tried to pull messages after pushing new changes. But, there is no messages from source repository.
What's the problem with me? What can I do more? Please help me.

Comment: what do you see when you run `gcloud alpha pubsub topics describe test`?

Comment: it shows just name of topic

Comment: ok, I don't know what could be wrong. have a look here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot solve this problem by documents. My topic is published well when i use it on cloud console. but only source repos does not publish messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your scenario and it worked for me, it could have been a transient issue. 
When you followed it, it appeared to be in Beta state.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-adding-pubsub-notifications#top_of_page) was the tutorial I followed, although, the only difference was that I used the gcloud commands without the "beta" argument:

i.e.

```
gcloud source repos update hello-world --add-topic=csr-test
```

Instead of

```
gcloud beta source repos update hello-world --add-topic=csr-test
```

Here is a reference for the PubSubConfig [Rest API](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubConfig)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue trying to verify that a cloud source repository published change to a topic. The problem was I needed the full name of the subscription in the pull command:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull projects/[my-project-id]/subscriptions/test-subscription
```

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-adding-pubsub-notifications#view_the_notification) uses only the base ID of `test-subscription` but that doesn't seem to be reliable.